# How to show custom fields in divi blog module?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, divi-theme

Theme: Divi 
Plugin for custom fields in post: ACF - Advanced Custom Fields

Using the Divi Blog module in Grid mode, I want to show a custom field (registered using the ACF plugin) alongside the post title, author, excerpt, post date, etc.

See the blue line in the screenshot to give you an idea.

[image]

Is there a way to have the Divi Blog module display a ACF field? Perhaps a editing the module function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help me .

Comment: You can add short code in content.

Comment: Is there any other way .. I mean editing any template ?

Comment: There are a few articles on how to customise Divi modules. [This is a good one.](https://github.com/eduard-ungureanu/Divi-tuts/wiki/How-to-customize-the-PHP-code-of-any-Divi-Module)

Answer (score 1):

Just did this successfully.

1. You first have to move the Blog module into your child theme using these instructions: https://intercom.help/elegantthemes/en/articles/4532734-moving-blog-module-in-child-theme
2. In your new, child theme Blog.php file, find the section that starts with the comment "Filters Blog module's main query." *For some reason there were what appeared to be two of this entire section in my file so make sure you're editing the last instance of this.*
3. Add your field values in the list right under the last one listed - it should be $thumb. My field in the example below is $start_date.

```
    $thumb     = $thumbnail['thumb'];
    $start_date = get_field('start_date');
```

4. Scroll down and find the place where you want to add your field within the article. (For example, I searched for 'class="entry-title"' in order to place my field below that.) Use some version of the following that works for the placement required.

```
<?php if($start_date) { ?>
    <div class="start_date"><?php the_field('start_date'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Divi provides an option to include Dynamic Content into Divi Builder. Not sure whether this works for the DIVI Blog Grid layout. Just give it a try and see if it works for you.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-releases/dynamic-content-for-divi-is-available-now

Comment: It doesn't work. This should be a comment, not an answer.