# Customizing Divi Blog module for ACF

Tags: module, blogs, divi, customizing

I found this topic
[How to show custom fields in divi blog module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665281/how-to-show-custom-fields-in-divi-blog-module)
but I didn't understand where I can add my fields.
It seems that the code of the module have change since december 2022.
I'm in the step I must add the fields like that, but I can't figure out where:

```
<?php if($my_field) { ?>
    <div class="my_field"><?php the_field('my_field'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there someone who did this recently?
Caroline